# release() in unique_ptr C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I have been working with `unique_ptr` for few days now and I have a question about the release method of `unique_ptr`. I know that release returns the *"Pointer to the managed object or `nullptr` if there was no managed object"*.

Lets say we have three `unique_ptr` variables:

```
unique_ptr< Node > left(Node);
unique_ptr< Node > right(Node);
unique_ptr< Node > middle(Node);
```

Now I want to change the pointers inside them:

```
middle.release();
right.release();
left.release();

middle.reset(right.get());
right.reset(left.get());
left.reset(middle.get());
```

Would this cause any memory leak? Is it better to store the values returned by `release()` and then use them or is it fine this way?

Comment: You could just call `reset` without release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaking! `release` nullifies the pointer. You lose the original object pointers.

What you want is accomplished by simply swapping twice:

```
middle.swap(right);
right.swap(left);
```

Comment: Awesome, I will accept this as the best answer when SO lets me :)

Comment: What? SO doesn't let the person who asked the question accept an answer??

Comment: @RustyX - There's a cooldown period, 15 minutes IIRC. You can't accept before it passes

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) `release()` does the following:

> Releases the ownership of the managed object if any. get() returns nullptr after the call.

So, once you released all your objects, you have lost your pointers! And since they were **owned** by the `unique_ptr`-s, they are now in the wild!

Instead, use swap to achieve the same goal carefully:

```
right.swap(middle); // middle = right, right = middle
right.swap(left); // left = right = (old) middle, right = left
```